# Set cursor color in an android webview

Tags: android, webview, contenteditable

I have text in an contentEditable in an android WebView that's white on black (to match the holo theme). Right now, when clicking inside the contentEditable in the android WebView, the cursor is invisible since it is black by default. Is there any way to manually change the cursor color when the WebView is focused?